# UIImagePickerController Edited Image - Convert NSRect to CGRect in Swift 2

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, image, mobile

I'm trying to crop an image that has been selected and edited through the UIImagePicker. For some reasons the picker doesn't return a `UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage` value. So what I'm trying to do is to get the original value and crop it according to the rectangle in `UIImagePickerControllerCropRect` but that's a `NSRect` and I need to convert it to a `CRRect` to crop it. This is my image picker controller function :

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {
        //Cut photo or show subview
        let chosenImage : UIImage
        print(editingInfo)
        if let possibleImage = editingInfo!["UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"] as? UIImage {
            print("Edited image")
            chosenImage = possibleImage

        } else if let possibleImage = editingInfo!["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] as? UIImage {
            print("Non edited image")

            if let rectangle = editingInfo!["UIImagePickerControllerCropRect"] as? [[Int]] {

                print(rectangle[0])

            }

            let rect: CGRect = CGRectMake(0, 230, 750, 750)


            let imageRef: CGImageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(possibleImage.CGImage, rect)!

            let image: UIImage = UIImage(CGImage: imageRef, scale: image.scale, orientation: image.imageOrientation)
            chosenImage = image
        } else {
            return
        }


        self.profilePicture.image = chosenImage.rounded?.circle
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true) { () -> Void in

        //update the server
        }
    }
```

Everything else works fine except it crops the image according to the rectangle in `CGRectMake(0, 230, 750, 750)` I'd like to make that instead of fixed values the values of `UIImagePickerControllerCropRect` . Please let me know if you have any suggestion on how to get that.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```
var rect: CGRect = CGRectMake(0, 230, 750, 750)
if let rectangle = editingInfo!["UIImagePickerControllerCropRect"] as? NSValue { 
  rect = rectangle.CGRectValue()
}

let imageRef: CGImageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(possibleImage.CGImage, rect)!
```

You used wrong variable I suppose

Comment: In Swift 4, CGImageCreateWithImageInRect has been replaced to cgImage.cropping(to:rect)